# What is the black two-leg sensor?

Tags: solar-cell, system, tracking

This is part of the Auto Sun Tracking Pump. It is attached to the agriculture solar system but damaged and I want to replace it. I don't know the black two-leg sensor.[image]

Comment: You've given us clear pictures of some terminal blocks, and not the sensor - which I take to be the black thing on the end.

Comment: ... and please crop the photos. That one is > 75% irrelevant background (including your feet).

Comment: Q1 More detail of the associated parts would help. Q2 What is the sensor located near? It could be a magnetic position sensor or .... .  Q3 Brand and model of equipment?

Comment: Toes. They sense immovable objects in the dark. They're quite effective.

Comment: What was the sensor next to? What are the markings on the face against the connector block?